# What is the relationship between the figure and the plot scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to overlay an image on a plot but I'm not sure how to map the coordinates of the figure to the scale on the plot.

```
import pylab
from PIL import Image
from urllib2 import urlopen
from StringIO import StringIO

url = "https://gravatar.com/avatar/e7b454a133dc67fe54d058a13bac9a67?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG"
img = Image.open(StringIO(urlopen(url).read()))

# Line intercept is the target location (4500, 45)
pylab.vlines(4500, 0, 50, color='red')

# Maps to (313, 213)?
pylab.figimage(img, 313, 213, zorder=1)

pylab.plot(range(0, 5000, 100), range(50))
pylab.show()
```

The target location is `(4500, 45)` on the plot but `pylab.figimage(img, 4500, 45)` would place the image somewhere far off the right side of the plot. By trial and error I found `(313, 213)` maps to about where I want the image placed.

[image]

What is the general relationship between the figure scale and plot scale?

Comment: Check out the table of coordinate systems in http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/transforms_tutorial.html (right at the top)